# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n +1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let's observe following matrix with an infinite number of elements :

[image]

Elements of the main diagonal are of the form $n\cdot2^n+1$ . These numbers are known as [Cullen numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cullen_prime) . It is an [open question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics#Number_theory:_prime_numbers) whether there is an infinite number of Cullen primes. In fact Cullen prime is special case of prime number of the $k\cdot 2^n +1$ form.

So, maybe easier question is : Are there infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n +1$ ?

Comment: Every prime $p$ that is congruent to $1$ modulo $4$ is of the form $4m+1$ for some $m$. Write $m=2^ak$ with $k$ odd, then $p=k2^{a+2}+1$. If $n$ is supposed to be fixed, then just look for the primes of this form greater than an appropriate bound. Or did you mean to both fix $n$ and require $k$ odd?

Comment: So the answer is "yes", and in fact, the OEIS has sequences for the least odd $k$ for any given $n$ [here](http://oeis.org/A057778)

Comment: @Arturo,I am interested in a formal proof that there are infinitely many primes of the form $k \cdot 2^n+1 $ if one exists,no special constraints.

Comment: @Arturo,If it is so what we may conclude about number of Cullen primes ?

Comment: marty cohen's argument gives a formal proof. Take the arithmetic progression $a+bm$ with $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $a=2^n+1$, $b=2^n$. Since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, then the progression has infinitely many primes. And $a+bm = (m+1)2^n+1$. This shows that for *each* $n$ there are infinitely many primes of the given form.

Comment: Obviously, not much, since the existence of infinitely many Cullen primes is open. Note that with Cullen primes, you are "moving" both the $n$ and the $k$, and here $k$ and $n$ are independent. That's what lets you use Dirichlet's Theorem.

Comment: @Arturo,Ok,I understand how to write formal proof.I think that one can make analogy : "If we know that there is an infinite number of quadrilaterals can we prove that there is infinite number of rectangles "

Comment: Cullen is equivalent to there being infinitely many $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$ that aren't representable as $k+(2\cdot k+1)\cdot b$ for any $k,b$ greater than 0...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first row of the OP's matrix is 3,5,7,..., and so obviously contains every prime except 2.  More generally, [Dirichlet's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) implies that each row contains an infinite number of primes (as pointed out by marty cohen).

A [Sierpinski number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_number) is a odd positive integer $k$ such that $k \cdot 2^n +1$ is composite for all $n \geq 1$.  The smallest known Sierpinski number is $78557$ [the [Seventeen or Bust](http://www.seventeenorbust.com/) team are trying to (computationally) prove it is the smallest].  Sierpinski showed that there are an infinite number of Sierpinski numbers, so there are an infinite number of all-composite columns in the OP's matrix (which extends zyx's answer).

Numbers of the form $k \cdot 2^n+1$ with $k<2^n$ are (sometimes) referred to as [Proth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem).  [Proth's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth%27s_theorem) gives a necessary and sufficient condition for the primality of a Proth number.  Yves Gallot [proth.exe](http://primes.utm.edu/programs/gallot/) is an available implementation of Proth's Theorem.  Many of the [largest known primes](http://primes.utm.edu/primes/) are Proth primes.

Related are numbers of the form $k \cdot 2^n-1$, for which we can detect primality via the efficient [Lucas-Lehmer-Riesel test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer%E2%80%93Riesel_test), implemented by Jean Penné's [LLR](http://jean.penne.pagesperso-orange.fr/index2.html).  Also, there's [Mersenne numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime), for which there's the giant [GIMPS](http://www.mersenne.org/) project searching for large Mersenne primes.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple-minded answer from simple-minded (at least in this group) me: Yes.

Use Dirichlet's theorem on primes in an arithmetic progression, for any $n$,
the arithmetic progression $k 2^n+1$, $k = 1, 2, ...$
contains an infinite number of primes.

Comment: And if you want $k$ odd, start with $a=2^n+1$, $b=2\times 2^{n}$, and look at $a+bm$.

Answer (score 5):

There are values of $k$ for which all terms of the sequence $k.2^n + 1$ are composite.  The proof uses covering congruences, starting from Euler's factorization of the fifth Fermat number; a finite set of primes is constructed and a set of congruence conditions that cover all $n$, and each condition forces divisibility by one of the primes.

There is no known value of $k$ for which it is proven that infinitely many primes exist in the sequence $k2^n + 1$.