# Infinite primes represented by a power function?

Tags: number-theory

Can we find infinite many primes of the form $3\cdot 2^n-1$ or $2\cdot 3^n-1$ for some $n$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-k-cdot-2n-1.

Comment: Thanks for the link, so the problem is stil open?

Comment: I think so, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are harder versions of [Guy's Unsolved Problem](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387208602) number A18, which asks whether there are infinitely many primes of the form
$$ p = 2^n3^m \pm 1.$$
Your question amounts to holding either $n$ or $m$ fixed, which is a strictly smaller (and thus presumably even harder to handle) set of potential primes. I believe this remains open (and that it will remain open for a long time --- this set is simply too sparse for us to handle today).