# Is it known whether the number of Proth-primes is infinite?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

A prime number of the form $k\times 2^n+1$ with $n\ge 1\ ,\ k<2^n$
is called a Proth-prime.

> Is it known whether the number of Proth-primes is infinite ?

It seems to be almost surely true that there are infinite many proth-primes,
but I do not know a proof.

Comment: Proth primes are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A080076 along with many links & references to the literature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is an open question as to whether there are infinitely many Proth primes (see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proth_prime ). It is conjectured that there are.  It was shown in 2022 that the reciprocal sum of Proth primes converges to a real number near 0.747392479, substantially less than the value of 1.093322456 for the reciprocal sum of Proth numbers. See: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11139-021-00536-2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an infinite number of Proth primes (see the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-k-cdot-2n-1)). The essence of the proof is to use the fact, that every arithmetic progression $a+bm$ with $gcd (a,b)=1$ has infinitely many primes.

Comment: In the discussion, I did not find the restriction $k<2^n$, making a prime of the form $k\times 2^n+1$ a Proth-prime. Without this ristriction, it is clear that even the number of primes of the form $k\times2^n+1$ with a fixed $n$ is infinite.

Comment: In fact, without the restriction $k<2^n$, every odd prime is of the form $k\times 2^n+1$, and the number of odd primes is, of course, infinite.

Comment: Yes, but the Dirichlet's theorem works without any restriction of $k$. If you define your arithmetic progression $a + bm$ as $a = k \times 2^n+1$ and $b = k \times 2^n$, it will assure the existence of infinitely many primes in the sequence $k \times 2^n + 1$ for any value of $k$.

Comment: If $k$ is fixed, it is not clear, whether $k\times 2^n+1$ has infinite many primes. $k\times 2^n+1$ is not an arithmetic progression, if $n$ runs.

Comment: @Peter: See zyx's answer on the linked post, where it explicitly says that there are no known values of *k* for which infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot2^n+1$ are known to exist.