# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n+1$ for a fixed $n$ and odd $k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, dirichlet-series, distribution-of-primes

It is clear from Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions that for a fixed $n$, there are infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n+1$ for a fixed $n$ and $k=1,2,3,..$. However, what if we keep $k$ odd?

From Arturo's comment on [Are there infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n +1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-k-cdot-2n-1?noredirect=1&lq=1), he writes:

And if you want $k$ odd, start with $a=2^n+1$, $b=2^n\cdot 2$, and look at $a+bm$.

Can someone explain whether this is correct and why, and whether this proved there are infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n+1$ for a fixed $n$ and odd $k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's still an arithmetic progression: $k = 2m + 1$ for some integer $m$, and your form is then $2^{n+1}m + (2^n + 1)$, which is still an arithmetic progression satisfying the hypotheses of Dirichlet's Theorem, so there are still infinitely many primes of that form.

Comment: $\gcd(2^n+1,2^{n+1}) = 1$ is important

Comment: Indeed it is. Added something about that.

Comment: How does / does this prove my question, though?

Comment: The $a$ and $b$ in your question are precisely the constant term and coefficient of $m$ in my answer.

Comment: @TejasRao For every $m$ for which $2^{n+1}\cdot m+2^n+1$ is prime, you can choose $k=2m+1$ and get $2^n\cdot k+1$ with an odd $k$. Since infinite many $m$ do the job, infinite many primes of the desired form must exist.