# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $2^n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many primes of the form $2^n+1$?

For some reason can't find anything concrete. I think $2^n-1$ is unknown. But what about $2^n+1$?

Comment: If $2^n+1$ is prime then $n=2^m$ (why?). Therefore,  you are asking if $2^{2^m} + 1$ is a prime number infinitely often? This is, not surprisingly, an unsolved problem and these are called Fermat primes.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki because there is this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-k-cdot-2n-1 and the guys there are saying that there are. Are they wrong?

Comment: This is unknown. $n$ must be a power of $2$ for it to be prime, and we call such primes Fermat primes, and we only know a finite number of theme - something like $5?$

Comment: This is also an unsolved question.

Comment: K thank you guys

Comment: @Goodie123 re: "Are they wrong?", the question you linked is not about $2^n+1$, it is about $k2^n+1$.

Comment: While only $5$ are known,  a famous mathematician thought there were infinitely many.  Was it Eisenstein?  Can't recall.   I'm sure one of you knows.

Comment: @hawaiianearringgroup FYI, Wikipedia's [Fermat number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) article's [Primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number#Primality) section has an open problems bullet point of "Are there infinitely many Fermat primes? (Eisenstein $1844$)".

Comment: It is easy to show that if $2^n+1$ is prime then $n$ is a power of $2$. A number $2^{2^m}+1$ is called a Fermat number. A Fermat number which is prime is called a Fermat prime. The only known Fermat $primes$ are for $m\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}.$ It is unknown whether there are any more Fermat primes. It is easy to show that if $2^n-1$ is prime then $n$ is prime. A number $2^p-1$, when $p$ is prime, is called a Mersenne number.  Many Mersenne numbers are prime and many are composite. It is unknown whether there are infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Comment: It is conjectured that there are infinite many Mersenne primes (primes of the form $2^p-1$ , where $p$ is a prime) , but this is also open. We currently know $51$ of them.

Comment: @Peter thanks.   BTW you wrote Einstein instead of Eisenstein.

Comment: @Chuang-tzu OK, I was confused. Now I understand that I just read the name wrong. Sorry.

Comment: Fermat conjectured that ALL Fermat numbers are prime. He was too lazy to check the fifth number. Ironically , now there are strong evidences that there is NO Fermat prime beyond $F_4=65537$. We cannot prove this , but the next candidate is so huge that there is almost no hope to find another such prime.

Comment: @Peter no worries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will try to explain a bit what is described in the comments, first, if we consider primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n+1$ we can affirm that there are infinitely many primes of that form, since it is evident that $(2^n ,1)=1$ and it is enough to apply the famous Dirichlet's theorem (if you want to know more about these primes I highly recommend [New Primes of the Form $k \cdot 2^n + 1$](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2006469)).  Now, if you are referring specifically to primes of the form $2^n+1$ (those related to Fermat and Mersenne primes), then (as mentioned in the comments) we don't have much information and know few.

Comment: Since you parenthetically write "those related to Fermat and Mersenne primes", you might more accurately write "..primes of the form $2^n \pm 1$ just before the parenthetic remark. [Of course there are quite a few known Mersenne primes.]

Comment: We don’t need the full power of Dirichlet to produce infinitely many primes congruent to $1$ mod $2^n$. It’s more elementary than that – $\Phi_{2^n}$ has infinitely many prime divisors, and all the odd ones are congruent to $1$ mod $2^n$.

Comment: Every odd integer $m>1$ can be written as $2^n\cdot k+1$ , primes of this form become special if we demand $k<2^n$ and $k$ odd. In this case , we have so-called Proth primes. Without this restriction it is obvious that there are infinite many such prime numbers since every odd prime can be written this way.

Comment: We cannot prove the results but there are heuristics predicting infinite many Mersenne primes and finite many Fermat primes. In fact , the chance that the list of Fermat primes is not complete , is about $1:10^9$