# Generating a random prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization, primality-test, prime-gaps

How can I generate **a** random prime of the form $2^ab+1$ for small $b$ value **without** actually creating a list of such primes, and then choose from the list at random?

*For example*: I can generate a random n bit prime by choosing a random n bit integer  $\textbf{c}$ from $[2^n,2^{n+1}],$ and then pick the next prime (or the previous prime) after $\textbf{c}.$

Does there exist such strategy for primes of the form $2^ab+1$? Any idea or suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take a look at this [Are there infinitely many primes of the form $k\cdot 2^n +1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79419/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-k-cdot-2n-1).

Comment: There is nothing better than to create random candidates without a small factor until you have a prime.

Comment: And what does "random" mean ? Which ranges are allowed for $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: At least such primes (called Proth primes" , if $2^a>b$ and $b$ odd) can be efficiently proven to be prime.

Comment: I cannot see a restriction of $k$ in the linked question. And without such a restriction , EVERY odd prime can be written this way. Here, $b$ is demanded to be "small".

Comment: @Peter I want $2^a$ to be really large and $b$ small. For example, something like $p=2^{32} \times 43 +1.$

Comment: Does the method need to be efficient? Following your example, you can generate $a,b$ randomly and then increment $b$ until you find a prime (which you will eventually, in fact you can meet infinitely many primes that way)? I am not sure if you are really clear about what you need.

Comment: Proth’s Theorem makes the testing very fast. If $b<10a$ is small/fixed, around $1/a$ of the numbers are prime  and prime testing takes time $a$, so you should find a prime in $O(a^2)$, so this should work for practical purposes (there’s some log factors in there due to $b$ which I’m ignoring).

Comment: Would you please explain why, in your example, this should be just straightforward and efficient? I mean, the distribution of the primes in a range can dramatically (pseudo-randomly) vary. The same arises for the very case if we pick a random value of $b$, sieve around the resulting number $2^a b+1$, and find a probably proximate prime. In your example, you practically sieve in a region with good hope, you do not get a prime immediately as a gift. I wonder whether you could help explain this please.

Comment: If there are infinitely many problems of this form, which the prime number theorem shows is likely, there's no uniform random distribution.

Comment: Assuming nothing is special about a number $n$, it’d be prime with probability around $1/ln(n)$ (higher actually since your numbers are odd). If you check ~$10ln(n)$ numbers of size ~$n$, the chance you find none is less than $e^{-10}\approx .01\%$.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is known that there are infinite many Proth-primes (although this seems obvious). As said , we can prove the primeness effciently , but it is not easier to FIND such primes compared to any other prime numbers with the same magnitude. So, if you want to find huge new (random) Proth primes fast , I must disappoint you.